# Json.Net ignore serialized private fields in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I would like to ignore serialized private fields from json serialization, but it seems that `[JsonIgnore]` works only with `public` fields, it does not work with `[SerializeField]` `private` fields. Is there any other way to ignore those fields?

This is an example class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ExampleObject : MonoBehaviour {
    [JsonProperty]
    private string property = "Property";

    [JsonIgnore]
    [SerializeField]
    private string ignored = "Ignored";
}
```

Output

```
{"property":"Property","ignored":"Ignored"}
```

It still serializes the `ignored` field to json, even though I am using `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` on the class and `[JsonIgnore]` on the `private` field.

`MemberSerialization.OptIn` says that

> "Only members marked with `JsonPropertyAttribute` or `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute` are serialized"

, but it also seems to include `SerializeField` attributes.

Edit: I am using `JilleJr Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity` ([github link](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity)) with `JilleJr Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters`([github link](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters))

Comment: What is the purpouse of [SerializeField] attribute?

Comment: That's a nice question. I searched [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) on the documentation but it shows a public property only. [Here](https://blog.rsuter.com/advanced-newtonsoft-json-dynamically-rename-or-ignore-properties-without-changing-the-serialized-class/) at this post you can see how the guy use a method `IsIgnored` by searching for the type of the property. That or [this](https://www.niceonecode.com/question/20711/newtonsoft-json-ignore-property-dynamically-during-serialization) post may help.

Comment: If you want to exclude the private field then why don't you use the default opt-out behaviour? *By default a type's properties are serialized in opt-out mode. What that means is that all public fields and properties with getters are automatically serialized to JSON, and fields and properties that shouldn't be serialized are opted-out by placing JsonIgnoreAttribute on them. To serialize private members, the JsonPropertyAttribute can be placed on private fields and properties* - [Source](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Objects)

Comment: Are you using Json.NET from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ or some Unity-specific port?  If so, what port/version?  If I simply serialize a DTO with the same properties as your `ExampleObject` then `ignored` is not serialized, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZeOSf7.  This leads me to believe you are using a version of Json.NET that has been tweaked for Unity, since vanilla Json.NET does not know about `[SerializeField]`.

Comment: Looks like `UnityTypeContractResolver` always includes members marked with `SerializeField`, see [the source](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters/blob/master/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters/UnityConverters/UnityTypeContractResolver.cs#L21).  You may need to subclass this contract resolver.  How are you invoking the serializer?

Comment: @Serge [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) .. as the name suggests it allows to serialize also private fields (by default only public fields are serialized) .. it also allows to serialize properties but that's not relevant for the question I guess ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for help.  I know what is  [SerializeField] for. I don't know why it is here if OP doesn't want to serialize it.

Comment: @Serge sounds like OP wants to expose it in the Inspector but omit it in the JSON serialization

Comment: @derHugo This is what I am trying to undestand. Why it should be exposed if it is private?

Comment: @Serge Why not? ^^ This is how the Unity Inspector works and it often makes a lot of sense that a field is private but exposed in the Inspector => encapsulation. The field can only be adjusted vis the Inspector and not accessed in another way

Comment: @PeterCsala Using opt-out causes this error: `JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'gameObject' with type 'UnityEngine.GameObject'. Path 'gameObject'.`

Comment: @dbc I am using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this)` for serializing the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the port of Json.NET that you are using, [JilleJr Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters), includes a custom contract resolver [`UnityTypeContractResolver`](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters/blob/master/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters/UnityConverters/UnityTypeContractResolver.cs) that includes members marked with `[SerializeField]` **even when also marked with `[JsonIgnore]`**.  From the [source](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters/blob/master/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity.Converters/UnityConverters/UnityTypeContractResolver.cs#L21):

> ```
> protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
> {
>    JsonProperty jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
>
>    // A check for member.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>() is missing in the following line:
>    if (member.GetCustomAttribute<SerializeField>() != null) 
>    {
>        jsonProperty.Ignored = false;
>        jsonProperty.Writable = CanWriteMemberWithSerializeField(member);
>        jsonProperty.Readable = CanReadMemberWithSerializeField(member);
>        jsonProperty.HasMemberAttribute = true;
>    }
>
>    return jsonProperty;
> }
> ```

If you don't want this, you will need to subclass this contract resolver and correct the behavior:

```
public class FixedUnityTypeContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.UnityConverters.UnityTypeContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
       JsonProperty jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

       if (!jsonProperty.Ignored && member.GetCustomAttribute<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute>() != null) 
           jsonProperty.Ignored = true;

       return jsonProperty;
    }
}
```

And then serialize as follows:

```
// Cache and reuse the contract resolver throughout your project to improve performance.
static Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver _resolver = new FixedUnityTypeContractResolver ();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    ContractResolver = _resolver,
};
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, settings);
```

Comment: Note - not tested since I don't have Unity installed where I am currently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it now works correctly when using `[JsonIgnore]` attribute. Do you know if there is any way to make the `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` work with this system, so that I don't have to add `[JsonIgnore]` to every serialized private field? You don't need to write a whole answer to that, you can just point me in the right direction so that I know where to look for an answer. Json serializing is still pretty new to me, since I only have around 20 hours of experience with Json.

Comment: @Crossoni - Is what you really want to eliminate the functionality that automatically includes `[SerializeField]` members, and instead fall back to the default behavior of Json.NET?

Comment: I actually want the private `SerializeField` fields to work exactly like public fields, so that if I use `MemberSerialization.OptIn` they need to be marked with `[JsonProperty]` in order to be included and if I use `MemberSerialization.OptOut` they will be included in json by default. I tried removing the `Unity.Converters` package and it seems that I really don't need it at the moment in my project, but I might need it later. Without it though I need to mark all of the private `SerializeField` fields with `[JsonProperty]` or they are not included in json, which reverses the problem.